# Blocking ForEach until async event completes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am working with the ReportViewer control and a custom print job workflow that is causing me some problems. My code looks a little like this:

```
        ids.ForEach(delegate(Guid? guid)
            {
                var details = items.Where(e => e.guid == guid);

                var ds = new ReportDataSource("Form", details);
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
                ReportViewer.RefreshReport();

            });
```

When `RefreshReport()` is called eventually it fires its `RenderingComplete` event and it is in that event where I have logic to queue a print job:

```
        if (DisplayPrintDialog) ReportViewer.PrintDialog();
        else
        {
            var document = new PrintDocument(ReportViewer.LocalReport);
            document.PrinterSettings = ReportViewer.PrinterSettings;
            document.Print();
        }
        DisplayPrintDialog = false;
```

The issue is that the ForEach loop finishes running before the `RenderingComplete` event fires so I need a way to block my ForEach loop until the RenderingComplete event fires for each pass of the loop.  What is a good way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Spike's snippet is a good example of signaling it falls short of solving my problem (by no fault of their own) and to even adapt their idea would make the code more convoluted than it needs to be.

After mulling this problem over I was able to segregate the ReportViewer control and this particular process.  That is to say I have removed the need for the ReportViewer control (and thus the need for signaling) in this particular workflow and come up with something a little bit more straightforward.

```
foreach (var item in guids)
{
     var details = items.Where(e => e.guid == item);
     var report = new LocalReport
         {
            ReportPath = [Path]
         };

     var ds = new ReportDataSource("Form", details);
     report.DataSources.Clear();
     report.DataSources.Add(ds);

     printingInvoked = ProcessPrintJob(report);

     if (!printingInvoked) break;
}
```

This is similar to my original code with the major difference being that I am creating an instance of a LocalReport and working with that directly instead of the ReportViewer's LocalReport property.  Then we actually handle the print job:

```
if (DisplayPrintDialog)
{
     if (PrintWindow.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
     {
          return false;
     }   
}

var document = new PrintDocument(report);
document.PrinterSettings = PrintWindow.PrinterSettings;
document.Print();

DisplayPrintDialog = false;
return true;
```

In this case PrintWindow is of type PrintDialog and PrintDocument is an extension of System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument to handle the actual RDLC files. All this is doing of course is initially prompting the user for their printer settings and then rifling *n* hydrated reports to the printer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

If you must keep this inside a foreach, use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

```
// Define this elsewhere in your class
static AutoResetEvent reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// This assumes RenderingComplete takes 1 argument, 
// and you aren't going to use it. If you are, change
// the _ to something more meaningful.
ReportViewer.RenderingComplete += _ =>
{
    // This happens after the code below, and this tells the "WaitOne" 
    // lock that it can continue on with the rest of the code.
    reset.Set();
}

ids.ForEach(guid => 
{
    var details = items.Where(e => e.guid == guid);

    var ds = new ReportDataSource("Form", details);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);

    // Begin the async refresh
    ReportViewer.RefreshReport();

    reset.WaitOne(); // This call will block until "reset.Set()" is called.
    reset.Reset(); // This resets the state for the next loop iteration.
});
```

I took the liberty of making your anonymous delegates less ugly, too (at this point there's no real reason to use the keyword `delegate` anymore, you should use the shorthand `() => { ... }` instead).

Comment: really? wouldn't the `reset.WaitOne();` block UI thread and stall everything into a deadlock?

Comment: Also, you are re-subscribing new delegate to `ReportViewer.RenderingComplete` very iteration of foreach, which will cause `reset.Set();` to be called more times than required.

Comment: OP didn't specify if this was a UI thread or not, I don't particularly care if it blocks the UI, they're the ones that want to turn an async operation into a sync one, not me. :) Also, good catch on the event, I fixed that.

Comment: YK1 is correct: it blocks the UI thread.  While I don't particularly like the idea of turning an async operation into a sync one I don't control the business requirements and nor am I able to get the powers that be to budge on this particular issue.

Comment: @abszero Don't forget to click the green checkmark to accept this answer if it worked for you. This lets other people know that this code is correct and solved the problem.